# Transform Polynomial to Standard Form in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, computer-science, polynomial-math, simplification

In Haskell, I'm using a custom data type of `Poly a = X | Coef a | Sum (Poly a) (Poly a) | Prod (Poly a) (Poly a) deriving (Show)`.

As such, the polynomial (3+x)^2 would be represented as `(Prod (Sum (Coef 3) X) (Sum (Coef 3) X))`.

I am having difficulty converting a polynomial entered this way into a list of coefficients of its standard form, which I believe would be `[9, 6, 1]` as (3+x)^2 = 9 + 6x + x^2.

I believe a possible solution would be to implement some math functions on my polynomial data types so that I could simplify an input, but I have been unsuccessful in doing this. Is there another way?

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Don't simplify on your `Poly` type, simplify directly to the list of coefficients.

Comment: I've tried making the simplification rules but it seems that there are so many that I cannot list them all. I am sure there has to be a finite amount, however. And sometimes the new rules break the old ones

Answer (score 6):

Don't simplify on your `Poly` type, simplify directly to the list of coefficients. Also maybe have the list of coefficients reversed (the first element for `^0`, the second for `^1`, the third for `^2` etc), I think that makes it easier.

```
data Poly a = X | Coef a | Sum (Poly a) (Poly a) | Prod (Poly a) (Poly a) deriving (Show)

toList :: Num a => Poly a -> [a]
toList X = [0, 1]
toList (Coef a) = [a]
toList (Sum a b) = let a' = toList a …
toList (Prod a b) = let a' = toList a …
```

I'll leave the actual implementation of how to merge the lists `a'` and `b'` for `Sum` and `Prod` respectively as an exercise.

If you want, you can also make a `toPoly :: [a] -> Poly a` function that converts from the list into the standard form of polynomials.

Comment: That's so cool. If I understand where this is going, `Sum` would be transformed using the `ZipList` applicative, and `Prod` would be implemented using the `[]` applicative?

Comment: @4castle `zipWith (+)` isn't going to be enough, as it requires the lists to be of the same length. Also [polynomial multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_multiplication) is a bit more complicated than nested lists. I think two custom recursive helper functions are required.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for guiding me on which direction to head! So will those four pattern matches suffice in creating a list of the coefficients if I find the correct way to combine list a' and list b' in both the (Sum a b) and (Prod a b) pattern marches, or will more recursive code outside these pattern matches be necessary?

Comment: @JackBuckley The four patterns are exhaustive (they match all possible cases).